# Why this code gives a run time error in timus 1086 problem?

Tags: c++

What is the problem with this code? It's nth prime number generator. It gives me the right answer but it gives a run time error in the second test case in Timus online judge. Can anyone please help me? Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

#define MAX 16000
bool prime[MAX];

void sieve() {
    prime[0]=prime[1]=true;
    int r=sqrt(MAX);
    for(int i = 3; i <= r; i++) {
        for(int j = i*i; j <= MAX; j+=(2*i)) {
            prime[j]=true;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int t, n;
    sieve();
    cin >> t;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> n;
        int c = 1, k, tk=2;
        for(k = 3; c < n; k+=2) {
            if(k%2!=0 && prime[k]==false) {
                c++;
                tk = k;
            }
        }
        cout << tk << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int j = i*i; j <= MAX; j+=(2*i)) { prime[j]=true;` -- What happens if `j == MAX`?  This is one reason why learning how to write safe C++ code cannot be learned from online competition websites.  Using `std::vector` and `vector::at()` would have pinpointed this issue.

Comment: What is the exact writing of the question? In particular max values of  `n`, `t` ?

Comment: @Damien, the max values of n, t is 15000.

Comment: If the max value of  `n` is 15000, then the max prime number will be much higher than 16000

Comment: Oh, I make this mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One glaring error is this one:

```
#define MAX 16000
bool prime[MAX];
// ...
for(int j = i*i; j <= MAX; j+=(2*i)) {
   prime[j]=true; // <-- Buffer overrun when j == MAX
```

When `j == MAX`, you are writing to `prime[MAX]`, when the highest index is `MAX - 1`.  This is a buffer overrun, thus leading to undefined behavior.

Any loop that has `<=` as the condition to continue is considered suspect.  This erroneous use of `<=` in a `for` loop condition is one tell-tale sign that an off-by-one access may occur.

The condition probably should be:

```
for(int j = i*i; j < MAX; j+=(2*i)) {
   prime[j]=true;
```

---

As to the safer coding that C++ gives you, using `std::array<bool, MAX>`, and then the `at()` function would flag this:

```
#include <array>

#define MAX 16000
std::array<bool, MAX> prime;
// ...
for(int j = i*i; j <= MAX; j+=(2*i)) {
   prime.at(j) = true; // <-- std::out_of_range exception thrown
```

This would have thrown a `std::out_of_range` exception as soon as `j == MAX`, stopping your program from going forward with (hopefully) a description of why the exception was raised.